# Data frame not getting converted to numeric

Tags: r

I have 100 files in a list which I would access using:

```
my.data[[1]], my.data[[2]] ... my.data[[100]]
```

each of these is a data.frame containing 202 columns and 2080 rows and I would like to convert them to numeric class. I tried with:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  my.data[[i]] <- sapply(my.data[[i]], as.numeric)
}
```

but when I check the class after running this loop using:

```
class(my.data[[1]])
```

I get the class as "matrix".

Of course, I tried to check them with one of the data.frames before looping; that too gave me the same result.

Please help. Where I could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Try `mode(my.data[[1]])` or `typeof(my.data[[1]])`. They are numeric matrices. e.g. `class(matrix(1:9, ncol=3))` also returns `matrix`. (The reason they're matrices now and not data.frames is that `sapply` simplifies them to matrices if possible.) Also take a look at `class(my.data[[1]][, 1])` to see the class of the vector that forms the first column, for example (this should return `numeric`).

Comment: Does `my.data <- lapply(my.data, function(x) sapply(x, as.numeric))` work? If not, please provide a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: Sorry, if forgot to mention `simplify=F` as argument to `sapply`, which might help.

Comment: Does this work:  my.data[] <- lapply(my.data, function(x) {x[] <-lapply(x, as.numeric);x})

Comment: Thanks @coffeinjunky: Your code helped!! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  set.seed(49)
  my.data <- lapply(1:5, function(x) as.data.frame(matrix(as.character(sample(20,5*6,replace=TRUE)), ncol=6),stringsAsFactors=F))
  my.data[] <- lapply(my.data, function(x) {x[] <-lapply(x, as.numeric);x})
  str(my.data)
```